# Strategy to profile front end (js) performance issues on iPad Air 2

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

[image: Slowness]

Another odd timeline event where it doesn't even make network request for more than 5 seconds

[image: Slowness 2]

I have a performance issue on iPad Air 2 using Safari when reloading this page

http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/slow.html

The first time it is pretty fast; but refreshes after the 1st load are slow. (5-10 seconds) AND it doesn't happen every time. It is not a network issue because I have tried on local network with same results.

It is also not a server side performance issue as the url above is just a static html file.

It also doesn't appear to be a CSS issue as if I remove all CSS it is still slow.

What I have tried so far is to remove js files 1 by 1 to see if that helps. It has been really hard to narrow it down due to the random nature of the problem and that it only occurs on iPad.

Also I know that my CSS and js are not contacted or minified; as we are still doing active development.

If I remove all js it is fast.

We use third party scripts; but since the issue doesn't happen on desktop it is hard to use profiling tools.

I am looking for any methods to profile on iPad Air 2

I am running iOS 9.1; but this happens on 8 too.

Interesting note: it is slow when hitting refresh icon; but not tapping url and then go.

Comment: You can use Safari for debugging and profiling your web applications directly from any iOS device. You can also use the Xcode iOS simulator to load your code and use Safari again to debug it. Safari Menu -> Develop -> iPad / iPhone -> your device IP Address

Comment: @DaveGomez thanks for the tip. I opened the IOS simulator and reproduced problem/ Unfortunately the safari inspector on computer stops right around when the error happens. But it did give me information that it is getting stuck when it starts to download css files. I have posted a screenshot of it. NOTE: This is on a local network.

Comment: I fixed this problem by removing @import in css. And moving all css + js to the top of the page...I would still love to know why this breaks though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris you can't use the **@import** rule in other places different than the beginning of the document, that was the issue.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) about the **@import** rule:

> The **@import** CSS at-rule allows to import style rules from other style sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except **@charset** rules; as it is not a nested statement, it cannot be used inside conditional group at-rules.